# How can I find all elements and put them in a list using Selenium?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium, appium

I have a number of unit tests. I want to find all elements on my screen and put them into a list. I have tried something like the example below. However, I don't want to find a number of elements by their name; I just want to find them all.

Is it possible to do this using Selenium?

```
IList<WindowsElement> elements = driver.FindElementsByAccessibilityId(element);
Debug.WriteLine(elements);
Thread.Sleep(200);
if (elements.Count > 0)
{

}
```

Comment: Is this Windows Forms, WFP? Have you tried `form.Controls`?

Comment: @Andrew it's a unit test project

Comment: And what object is that being displayed on the screen, the one that contains your elements?

Comment: @Andrew It's just a string I am passing but I don't want to do it like this as I don't want to search for a certain element I want to add them all to a list then I want to do a `foreach` through though them and if an element in the list contains "PowerPoint is running into problems" in it's element name then do something

Comment: Are you by chance trying to find all windows currently running in your operating system, and not the controls of your displayed form?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are answering any of my questions in the comments, so I am not sure if I can help you. Anyway, I'll show you how to find controls in Winforms. If it's something else, you'll have to answer my question and tell us.

```
// Winforms. If this goes in another class, use the form variable instead of "this".
foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl.Name == "PowerPoint is running into problems")
    { 
        // Do your thing
    }
}
```